# Найти количество ненулевых цифр произвольного числа. Язык Си

Tags: c

Как найти кол-во ненулевых цифр произвольного числа? Си

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать цикл, в котором число будет постоянно уменьшаться в 10 раз.
На каждой итерации цифрой числа будет результат вычисления `number % 10`. Проверяешь на ноль и готово :)

```
int counter = 0;
int number = 1230;
while (number)
{
    if (number % 10)
        ++counter;
    number /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Можно убрать одно ветвление (https://godbolt.org/z/EGPzGM), делая вот так counter+=bool(number%10).
Устранение ветвлений делает процессор счастливее.

Comment: И в результате вы находите число нулевых символов, не не ненулевых, как в задании...